# Press any key with timeout progress displayed in shell

Tags: bash, timeout, pause

I want to provide user with a prompt to press any key or wait for a timeout to continue using shell. Usually this case is solved with following idiom:

```
read -rs -t3 -n1 "Press any key or wait to continue ..."
```

However this prompt seems a little bit clumsy to me and I would like to left only "Press any key to continue ..." part of a message and indicate timeout with dots printed each second. So I write following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Press any key to continue";

for _ in `seq 3`; do
    if ! read -rs -n1 -t1 ; then echo -n "."; else break; fi
done

echo
```

It works just as I expect, but obviously there is too much code, so I have to put in separate file instead of using as `sh -c "..."` in script. Is there a way to implement it in more concise and compact way?

P.S. Returning non-zero error code on `Ctrl-C` pressed is a must.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more concise :

```
echo -n "Press any key to continue";
for _ in {1..3}; do read -rs -n1 -t1 || printf ".";done;echo
```